# Pointclouds extraction using the Bumblebee2 stereo camera

Tags: slam, navigation, viso2-ros, viso2, bumblebee

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

This is my first results using the bumblebee2 and the "stereo_image_proc" node to extract pointclouds. I calibrated the camera with the "camera_calibration" node using the -k 6 option and got an epi ratio of around 0.25.
link:[PointCloud](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59gd4OU5u7A&feature=youtu.be%22PointCloud%22)

What do you think about this results ? is it possible to have a better calibration and a better pointcloud ?
what are the best calibration conditions ?
Is there any way to process this pointcloud to get the same result than this one : link:[viso2_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros%22viso2_ros%22)

Stephan, can you please tell me how did you process your pointcloud (The one in the video below) and what epi ratio you got after the calibration of your Bb2 ?
Does your "viso2_ros" perform the Slam that we can see in this same video ?
link:[viso2_Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=4Ze99YStmPo%22viso2_Video%22)

Thank you guys for your responses

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60020/pointclouds-extraction-using-the-bumblebee2-stereo-camera/) by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2013-04-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your clouds look very good!

Regarding the video on the viso2_ros wiki page: The object is at a distance of about 1m and it has a very good texture.
To get the reconstruction, we downsampled the point clouds using [VoxelGridFilter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros/Filters#VoxelGrid) and accumulated them in rviz using [viso2_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros) to generate odometry, setting the fixed frame in rviz to `/odom` and the decay time of the PointCloud2 display to 10 seconds. You can use [fovis_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fovis_ros) for the visual odometry as well. There is no SLAM algorithm in the background so the reconstruction will suffer from drift after a couple of seconds. I don't remember what we got as epipolar error during our calibration. I think 0.25 is okay.

EDIT:

If you want to slow down processing (stereo_image_proc can get quite busy on calculating point clouds) you can [throttle](http://www.ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/throttle) one input topic for stereo_image_proc.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [INSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4565/insa/) on 2013-04-04**:
Thank you Stephan for your help. What about the blank areas in the pointcloud ? Specially when i move the camera. How can i fill these empty spaces ? maybe with Temporal Filtering ? Your Pointcloud has no empty spaces...

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2013-04-05**:
I suppose the texture is not unique enough for block matching. You could try to adapt the stereo_image_proc parameters `correlation_window_size` and/or `uniqueness_ratio`. In the end, if there is no texture the algorithm is unable to match the area from left to right image. Paint your walls! ;-)